# XMLHttpRequest for connecting to a secure url

Tags: javascript, authentication, ssl, xmlhttprequest

I am using example code which I found here:
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_post2

I want to get a JSON string from an endpoint that requires authentication.

1. How do I specify my ID / Pass with the request being made to the endpoint ( Is there a HTTP header which I can use which would ask me to authenticate )?
2. What is a workaround for connecting to the url which might need us to authenticate?
3. How can I specify to use a SSL certificate for getting response?

```js
< script >
  function loadDoc() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", "demo_post2.asp", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send("fname=Henry&lname=Ford");
  } < /script>
```

Comment: Try using the header `"Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD)`

Comment: Where do I specify this? In xhttp.setRequestHeader? Do I need to get rid of the current one? Can I append this in the current one?

Comment: Add another request header as `xhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization",  "Basic " + btoa(USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD));`

Comment: Now i see the error as "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 415."

Comment: If your API and the page accessing it are not hosted on the same domain, then your API needs to handle CORS. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: I always thought .open had 5 parameters.  Method url asynch username password